# Issue with variables within the scriptblock of Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I seem to have a issue with getting variables in the `Invoke-Command`. I can't get a variable in whatever I do. When I want to use:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername  { new-item -Path "$RootPathDestination" -Name $version -Itemtype directory }
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
```

And I have declared them in this script:

```
$version = 36
$RootPathDestination = "c:\scripts\"
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I am really out of options here :-(

```
 $svr = "SQLSERVER"
    $db = "0000 - INFRA"
    $version = 36
    $RootPathDestination = "c:\scripts\"


    # connection
    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$svr;Database=$db;Integrated Security=True"

        $sqlConnection.Open()
         $cmd = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
         $cmd.CommandText ="SELECT * from infrastructure"
         $Serverinfo = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
         try
         {
             while ($Serverinfo.Read())
             {
               $servername = $Serverinfo.GetValue(1)
               Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername  { new-item -Path "$RootPathDestination" -Name $version -Itemtype directory }
               #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername { Copy-Item c:\scripts\* c:\test }
               #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername {Import-Module WebAdministration ; New-WebApplication -force  -Site "Default Web Site" -Name 3.78 -PhysicalPath "c:\inetpub\"$version }
             }
         }
         catch
         {
           echo "Hmm strange"
         }
         finally
         {
         echo "All good!"

         echo $Version



           $sqlConnection.Close() 
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a scriptblock to `Invoke-Command`. In order to use the values of any variables defined *outside* that scriptblock *within* the scriptblock, you need to refer to them as `$using:variablename` (in your example, `$using:RootPathDestination`. See [`Get-Help about_Remote_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables).

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! For all other users with the same options:   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername  { new-item -Path $Using:destinationpath -name $Using:versionnumber -Itemtype directory }

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the *using* prefix:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername  { new-item -Path "$using:RootPathDestination" -Name $using:version -Itemtype directory }
```